# MongoDB/mongoose | Extending Schema functionality

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I'am trying to give a Schema some custom fields, that describes its behaviour. I want to use it for some authentication, by giving a minumum "level", what someone needs to read its value.
The plan is to declare it just like making a field required, so I would write "minAuth: someLevel" in the field declaration.

I already tried this and it gives no error, but I cant really find the value anywhere.

Does somebody know, where I can access a Schemas fields properties?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So if your schema looks something like this:

```
YourSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: {type: 'String', minLevel: 1}
})
module.exports = mongoose.model('You', YourSchema);
```

Then you can import it, and use the schema variables like

```
const You = require("/path/to/schema/you")
// Get all fields from the schema
let path = You.schema.paths
  for ( const [index, PropertyName] of path) {
    const PropertyDescription = schema.paths[index]
    let Level = PropertyDescription.options.minLevel
  }


// Or you can go directly to it if you know the index of it

You.schema.paths[TheIndexYouKnow].options.NameOfYourCustomVariable
```

I hope this helps